# Gnosis Safe deployment on custom EVM chain

Tags: safe-core

I have a question. I have gone through the docs and understand the process of deploying safe onto my custom evm chain. However, there is an issue we are going to run into:

My chain has a proprietary consensus mechanism (Proof of Work by Authority) where only authorized wallets can deploy to the chain. We have a factory deployed to the chain that allows contracts to be deployed to a targeted address however, you must be an authorized wallet to use it.